# drupal views with contextual filter

Tags: nodes, views

I  have created a content type page named events where several fields are there. also I have created a  view page where list comes of events(title,body and read more). when we click on read more it takes me to the content display page

what I want to do is on display content page i want some sidebar links so that other fields should comes related to that particular node.

Comment: Do you mean, when viewing an Event page there would be a View on the sidebar that lists other Events as well that link to their page also?

Comment: links should be there on events page while clicking on that link a page should open where other fields comes related to that paricular event

Comment: I have created view page for them, but i think i am making the mistake in setting up the path for contextual filter from content id from url please help!!

Comment: In contextual filter you should select provide default values option and their will be one option content id from url.

Comment: Really sorry but can you please provide more information/screenshots of your work so far and the expected output? I cant quite understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

[image: this![enter image description here] is the view page of events when we click on read more its takes me to the content display page (the second image) like there are sponsers block is there of individual node above that i need page links to show other fields which i use to save during creating the node like speakers and other thingd][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z68hg.png)